# How I can get neighborhood from LatLng

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, street-address

Im trying get the neighborhood from a LatLng Object.

Im using Geocoder Object from Android API for do this.

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 5);
```

I get the neighborhood name sometimes, in List Address, but I don't know how differentiate the City Name with neighborhood name.

There are any way to differentiate it?

Answer (score -2):

You can call this Google Maps Reverse geocoing API with an optional API key.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=API_KEY
The result will be several JSON objects which will contain data like street name, area, city, state, pincode, etc separately.